# Unable to save dataframe in Jupyterlab to CSV/Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to export a dataframe in Jupyterlab. The command runs but I don't see the file on my desktop.
I'm trying this but I don't find the file. I've even tried to_excel version but that doesn't work either. Any help, pls.

```
df_busu.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\app_play_store.csv')
```

[image: to_csv]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to save without raw string format and inverting the "" to "/".

```
`df_busu.to_csv("C:/Users/.../file.csv"; sep=";")`
```

that's how a export a file to csv from pandas in Win10.

Comment: Hello. I'm getting this error.  File "<ipython-input-9-badb016e4643>", line 1
    df_busu.to_csv("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/file.csv"; sep=";")
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: sorry, 

df_busu.to_csv("C:/Users/.../file.csv", sep=";")

Comment: If I try `df_busu.to_csv("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/file.csv", sep=";")`, I get this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/file.csv'.

If I try `df_busu.to_csv("file.csv", sep=";")` , the command goes through but I'm not sure where does the file get saved?

Comment: if I open a jup lab in, let's say, 'documents' folder, it will be the working directory.

then, when I export the csv without a path, it will be saved at 'documents' folder

take a look the pic https://ibb.co/fdq86Ky